# Getting values from queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Facing troubles with getting values from foreign key models.
I have one model, where included all foreign key relations.

```
class UserAccount(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category= models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    permissions = models.ForeignKey(Permissions)


class Country(models.Model):
    iso_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I'm using this to get all fields related to model UserAccount:

```
user_account_data = UserAccount.objects.all()
name = user_account_data.values_list('name', flat=True)))
surname = user_account_data.values_list('surname', flat=True)))
```

But when trying this, its giving me: ***'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'country'***

```
countries = user_account_data.country.values('iso_code')
```

Comment: Please *don't* use `.values`/`.values_list`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: ok, anyway if I use only or filter its giving the same, because there is some issue for getting country model, that is the main trouble for me

Comment: use  `for item in user_account_data`, and then you can access `item.name`, `item.surname` and `item.country.iso_code`. You can boost efficiency by using `UserAccount.objects.select_related('country')`, but this will not erode the model layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
countries = user_account_data.values('country__iso_code')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values

Answer (score 1):

Please do *not* make use of [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [**`.values_list(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values_list): first of all you will here make one query for each value so if you evaluate `name`, `surname`, and `countries`, then you make three queries. Furthermore it is not even said that these queries will produce results in the same order, so matching the items will be a second problem, and finally this will produce dictionaries/lists of values: these thus "erode" the model layer, and introduce a [*primitive obsession* antipattern <sup>[refactoring.guru]</sup>](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).

Usually one works with model objects, you can thus fetch all the data for the `UserAccount` with the corresponding `Country` data with:

```
for item in UserAccount.objects.select_related('country'):
    print(item.name)
    print(item.surname)
    print(item.country.iso_code)
```

You can thus use these in a template, in a serializer, form, etc. It guarantees that the `.name`, `.surname` and `.country.iso_code` are of the *same* item. `item.country` is a `Country` object: so you can pass this to functions that work with a `Country` object (for example serialize, update, etc.). It is thus more convenient to work with model objects, than with dictionaries/lists/… that contain data of these objects.